# Find out duplicate words with differing case

Tags: vimscript, word-processing

I need to confirm I have not created duplicate variables in a c file, while converting code from another language which is case insensitive.

For example, a file's content (below 2 lines) is:

```
  x = data1;
  data2 = Data1+ X;
```

Above text has x and X, data1 and Data1 and I want to know all such variables in the file.

Comment: I have got this from search as a solution but this again required me to manually go through sorted words and that too it is not effective in splitting words.  cat <filename> | xargs -n1 | sed 's/\[/ /g' | xargs -n1 | sort

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit unclear on what you're looking for. You want to find all instances of `data1` or `Data1`, but you don't want it in a search pattern? What do you want it in then?

Comment: @Tmbler41  I want to know such repeated words with case differing, and if case doesn't differ, I dont need them.

Comment: How would you differentiate between code and variables?

Comment: There wont be such words in code, only variables might be created so, by mistake (or some other reasons). My language in context is C.

Answer (score 4):

The following script provides the `:Ambiguous` command.  It displays keywords (read `:h 'iskeyword'`) that are the same but have different letter case in the `location-list` window.

The script is explained through its comments:

```
function! s:display_ambiguous() abort
  let buckets = {}

  " Split all text in the buffer by non-keywords.
  for word in split(join(getline(1, '$')), '\%(\k\@!.\)\+')
    " Words are collected into a bucket, keyed by the lowercased word.
    let key = tolower(word)
    if !has_key(buckets, key)
      let buckets[key] = []
    endif

    " Only add words that haven't been seen before.
    if index(buckets[key], word) == -1
      call add(buckets[key], word)
    endif
  endfor

  let ambiguous = []
  for [key, items] in items(buckets)
    " If a bucket has more than one item, add it to the results.
    if len(items) > 1
      call add(ambiguous, {
            \ 'text': join(items, ', '),
            \ 'bufnr': bufnr('%'),
            \ })
    endif
  endfor

  if !empty(ambiguous)
    " Set the contents of the location-list window.
    call setloclist(0, ambiguous, 'r')
    " Display the location-list window.
    lopen
  endif
endfunction


command! Ambiguous call s:display_ambiguous()
```

Comment: FWIW I agree with your last edit, but just to be clear, I make a lot of mistakes, and I also see other people doing a lot. Usually I don't try to fix them because they're not important / relevant to the question. But here, when I tried the code it didn't work at all because in Vim (could be wrong) it seems the list is ignored if you give a fourth argument. So I tried to fix the code so that it works as intended both in Vim and Neovim.

Comment: By the way, I like your answers in general, they frequently make me learn something. Here for example, it made me learn how to simulate the pseudo-class `\K` inside the pattern `\K\+` (sequence of non keyword characters). So far, I tried to do it like this: `[^a-zA-Z_0-9\d192-\d255]\+`. But your version is more readable, and takes into account the current value of `'isk'`: `\%(\k\@!.\)\+`

Comment: @user9433424 No sweat! It was actually my bad since I use Neovim and didn't realize the fourth argument was different from Vim's. Setting the quickfix title wasn't relevant to the question, so I thought it'd be better to just remove it and avoid confusion.  Sorry if it seemed like a silent, passive-aggressive edit. SE doesn't make it easy to discuss revisions. I'm glad you get useful information out of my long-winded posts :-)